# Flask Configuration for Sharing Resources Across Blueprints

Tags: python, flask

I have an extremely large application that is factored into many blueprints. I need to configure the entire application to save files into a directory when a user uploads files. So I am setting `["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = 'C:/some/path'` to the path where files would live after upload in the `app.py` file.

The documentation reads that configuration settings are shared across the blueprints. I'm experiencing one issue that is not working and below is a stripped down example to replicate my problem to support my question. So, to debug I've created an extremely simple version just printing the path to screen to see what is happening.

If I head over to the URL `.../print_dir` then the `["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = 'C:/some/path'` is printed to screen. However, if I head over to the URL defined within the blueprint `.../new` then I am given an error of `NameError: name 'server' is not defined`.

How can I configure my app such that the same `["SESSION_FILE_DIR"]` can be used across blueprints?

The contents of my main `app.py` are as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session
import tempfile

server = Flask(__name__)

server.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
server.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
server.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = 'C:/some/path'
server.secret_key = 'abcdefg'

### Import and Register Blueprints 
from tools.routes import my_bp

server.register_blueprint(my_bp)

@server.route('/')
def homepage():
    return "Hello"

@server.route('/print_dir')
def homepage2():
    return server.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.run(debug=True)
```

and now suppose the blueprint lives in a subdirectory called `tools` and contains the following:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, Blueprint
from flask_session import Session

my_bp = Blueprint("my_bp", __name__)

@my_bp.route('/new', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def path(): 
    path = server.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"]
    return path
```

Answer (score 3):

To access the `app.config` from within a `Blueprint`, you can import `current_app` from `flask`.

Example:

```py
# ./app.py
from flask import Flask
from views.blueprint import bp

app = Flask(__name__)

# Set the config you want:
app.config['IMPORTANT_DIRECTORY'] = '~/path/to/important/directory'

# Register your blueprint
app.register_blueprint(bp)
```

```py
# ./views/blueprint.py
from flask import Blueprint, current_app

bp = Blueprint('bp', __name__)

@bp.route('/path')
def get_path():
    # access the config
    path = current_app.config['IMPORTANT_DIRECTORY']
    return path
```

You can find more info in the [api docs for flask](http://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.current_app).